GraalVM native image fails on basic scala library
I have a very simple Scala project with ONLY the Scala library as dependency and using the assembly plugin to create a jar. SBT is:
name := "Bigjar"

version := "1.0.0"

scalaVersion := "3.4.2"

assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
}

build.properties is:
sbt.version=1.10.0

assembly.sbt is:
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "2.2.0")

Now:
native-image -jar target/scala-3.4.2/bigjar.jar

gives me:
========================================================================================================================
GraalVM Native Image: Generating 'bigjar' (executable)...
========================================================================================================================
[1/8] Initializing...                                                                                   (19.2s @ 0.11GB)
 Java version: 22.0.2+9, vendor version: Oracle GraalVM 22.0.2+9.1
 Graal compiler: optimization level: 2, target machine: armv8-a, PGO: off
 C compiler: cc (apple, arm64, 14.0.3)
 Garbage collector: Serial GC (max heap size: 80% of RAM)
 2 user-specific feature(s):
 - com.oracle.svm.polyglot.scala.ScalaFeature
 - com.oracle.svm.thirdparty.gson.GsonFeature
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build resources:
 - 6.05GB of memory (75.6% of 8.00GB system memory, determined at start)
 - 8 thread(s) (100.0% of 8 available processor(s), determined at start)
[2/8] Performing analysis...  [***]                                                                     (17.5s @ 0.55GB)
    6,236 reachable types   (78.8% of    7,909 total)
    7,809 reachable fields  (49.9% of   15,646 total)
   33,070 reachable methods (46.8% of   70,627 total)
    1,840 types,    63 fields, and   817 methods registered for reflection
       59 types,    57 fields, and    53 methods registered for JNI access
        4 native libraries: -framework Foundation, dl, pthread, z
[3/8] Building universe...                                                                               (1.6s @ 0.65GB)

Warning: Reflection method java.lang.Class.getMethods invoked at scala.Enumeration.populateNameMap(Enumeration.scala:201)
Warning: Reflection method java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields invoked at scala.Enumeration.getFields$1(Enumeration.scala:195)
Warning: Reflection method java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields invoked at scala.Enumeration.getFields$1(Enumeration.scala:195)
Warning: Reflection method java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields invoked at scala.Enumeration.populateNameMap(Enumeration.scala:197)
Warning: Aborting stand-alone image build due to reflection use without configuration.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        1.6s (4.2% of total time) in 449 GCs | Peak RSS: 0.97GB | CPU load: 3.33
========================================================================================================================
Failed generating 'bigjar' after 38.6s.
Generating fallback image...
Warning: Image 'bigjar' is a fallback image that requires a JDK for execution (use --no-fallback to suppress fallback image generation and to print more detailed information why a fallback image was necessary).

I tried everything in GraalVM's docs regarding solving the above reflection issue but to no avail (Docs).
I don't use any Enumerations as the process describes above so it can only be a consequence of something in the Scala library itself.
What gives? Is the Scala library in itself with intractable reflections impossible to resolve outside of runtime? Do I need to get off Scala to be able to generate native code?
I also tried scala-native-image as described below.
plugins.sbt has:
logLevel := Level.Warn
addSbtPlugin("org.scalameta" % "sbt-native-image" % "0.3.4")

And changed my build.sbt to:
name := "Bigjar"

version := "1.0.0"

scalaVersion := "3.4.2"

lazy val example = project.enablePlugins(NativeImagePlugin).settings(
    mainClass.in(Compile) := Some("com.Launcher")
)

And doing sbt nativeImage gives me:
JVM graalvm-java11:20.2.0 not found in index: No graalvm-java11 version matching '20.2.0' found
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
[error]     at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:138)
[error]     at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:108)
[error]     at sbtnativeimage.NativeImagePlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$28(NativeImagePlugin.scala:218)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:63)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:69)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:283)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:24)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:292)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:283)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:65)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
[error] (example / nativeImageGraalHome) Nonzero exit value: 1
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Sep 24, 2024, 4:14:53 PM

All using Scala 3.4.2 and sbt 1.10.0 run of the mill latest greatest.
java -version gives me:
java version "22.0.2" 2024-07-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 22.0.2+9.1 (build 22.0.2+9-jvmci-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 22.0.2+9.1 (build 22.0.2+9-jvmci-b01, mixed mode, sharing)


There is no need to use assembly and then Graal, you can use Graal directly from sbt: https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/graalvm-native-image.html and https://github.com/scalameta/sbt-native-image - You may also evaluate if ScalaNative works for your use case.

I suspect that solution will still result in reflection warnings. Is there a way to force a native image disregarding those warnings? Neverless thanks for this tip.

Well those tools have been used to create native images of Scala apps without issues, especially very simple projects. So, I would advise using those and checking their docs.

From what I see sbt-native-image automates the process of: running main on JVM with native-image agent, using native image agent to generate the config for native-image, providing the config into actual native-image generation. What you are missing are all these params telling it what to do with reflection, initialization, etc that can be automatically generated with a Java agent.

I updated my description to include the most bare bones basic sbt-native-plugin config and still fails.

I found this example which is dated and proves scala 3 can be compiled into native code. Yet it doesn't work anymore? Leaky abstraction alert! I am this close from rewriting my code in C++ and forgeting about scala which is USELESS for high performance code. It will be faster than trying to coax a native executable from a scala source! Prove me wrong... https://github.com/tabdulradi/hello-scala3-native-image

I finally got it to work using --no-fallback
